# My monitor keep changing from DVI to VGA?

Tags: windows-7, dvi

I have a Samsung LED monitor plugged to a Dell PC (Windows 7) which keeps changing from DVI to VGA everytime it goes suspended or I turn off and turn on again to use the PC.

How do I stop it from changing every time?

Comment: What's the model number of the Samsung monitor in question?  To confirm, you are connecting it from DVI on the PC, to DVI on the monitor, with only a DVI cable (no converters or dongles)?

Answer (score 0):

Some of these monitors will have a default source video that it will check when first turns on or wakes up. I believe it is set to VGA which is causing your frustrations.

Comment: … and how would he change it?

Comment: click on the menu button and scroll through the settings. Without a model number specifically, it's difficult to say.

Comment: Does it turn itself on like my Syncmaster P2450?

Comment: I's a Philips 221EL2